# Floating point type the same size as a pointer

Tags: c, floating-point

Can you count on a semi-modern processor being able to do floating-point calculations with a piece of data the same size as a pointer?  Is there a defined type (possibly in a platform-specific header file) for such a type?  I'm after the effect of intptr_t but for floats.

Edit:
I'm not referring to C's `float` type, but to floating-point numbers in general.

Edit:
Do I need to just have a script run, testing what the sizes of `float`, double, and `void *` are for the compiler being used, and generate an appropriate header file to `typedef` a type that other code uses?

Comment: It would be interesting to know what are you trying to achieve. It may be something very clever or something rather silly, but it is certainly not something common.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to achieve. Most 64-bit machines do not have a floating point type large enough to store any possible pointer.

Comment: What if the floating point numbers are of bit-widths that are unaligned w.r.t. pointers?

Comment: @R: What about `long double`?

Comment: @Nemo: ARM processors with VFP are "semi-modern", and as far as I know they have nothing bigger than 64 bit IEEE double. Presumably in C implementations for them, `sizeof(long double) == sizeof(double)`. [Edit: but, hang on, they also have 32 bit pointers, so are not a counter-example. Um. But they're working on 64 bit architectures, so do we want an answer that's true for modern processors but not for the foreseeable future?]

Comment: @Steve:  @R's comment said "most 64-bit machines".  Are there really more ARM processors than x86 in the world?  Hm, maybe...  Still seems like a misleading comment given that every person reading this is almost certainly _on_ a machine with a floating point type capable of holding 64 bits of precision.

Comment: @Nemo: oh, sorry, didn't realise it was specifically the "most" that you objected to. Yes, x87-derived architectures including x86-64 do still have the 80 bit floating point type, although lots of people, possibly including your compiler-writers, don't want you to use it.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Aren't the largest pointers in use anywhere 64 bits?  Wouldn't any machine with DP floating point meet the requirement?

Comment: @grok12: it's still not clear what the requirement really is. R.. says, "a floating point type large enough to store any possible pointer", which seems to me a reasonable interpretation of "intptr_t but for floats", and that the questioner has incorrectly assumed that equal sizes are sufficient to provide this property. Given that we don't know what arithmetic is intended, I don't think we can confidently say that a 64 bit floating point type meets the requirements. It's possible that the requirements are very minimal, and hence that it would, subject to not trapping on signalling NaN, etc.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: It would be nice if OP would unveil his mysterious plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you will get is:

```
union floatptr_t {
    float f;
    void *p;
};
```

On the down side, this is not exactly what you asked for.  On the bright side, it is 100% standard...

[edit]

Yes, you could use `sizeof` to compare your pointer size to `float`, `double`, and `long double`, and pick one.  But as @R. points out, many pointer values will map to `NaN`, so you will not be able to do anything with those floating point values other than cast them back to a pointer...  And even that is not guaranteed to work (although it probably will in practice).

But if you cannot *do* anything with the floating point value except cast it back to a pointer, then you are better off using a union, since that will be just as space-efficient and will actually work portably.

Comment: almost, but sizeof float is 4, and sizeof void * is either 4 or 8 depending on the arch.  So I think instead of float you'd want to use double, and on 32-bit systems the top 4 bytes should sign-extend to all 0s.

Comment: With C++ one could use a template to select the corresponding type, but the solution would still be a kind of hacky (no such type is guaranteed to exist) and definitely strange (floating point calculations are in its nature inaccurate, using rounding - how could this be used for pointers is hard to imagine).

Comment: @Bobby, he said "float"...  And on a 32-bit platform `void *` is likely the same size.  The point is that it does not matter; if you need a data type that can hold either a pointer or a float, the standard way is to create a union.  Whether `double` makes more sense depends on what he is trying to achieve, which the question does not make clear

Comment: @Nemo: well, he started by saying 'floating-point calculations', and these days almost all desktops are 64-bit systems.  But, I was wrong anyway - section 6.2.6.1 of the C99 standard say that the padding in unions of different-length members take undefined values when smaller members are assigned to, so that makes it a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Bobby: Not to mention that there is no guarantee that "float" is 4 bytes, "double" is 8 bytes, "void *" is 4 or 8 bytes...  None of this is mandated by the standard, so you should never write code assuming it.

Comment: @R: I am assuming he is looking for a space-efficient way to hold a value that might be either a pointer or a floating-point number.

Comment: A configuration script to check sizes of void *, int, float, etc. and generate a union in an appropriate header file does it.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly very common, since "semi-modern" processors pretty much all have CHAR_BIT 8 and object pointer size either 4 or 8, and pretty much all support IEEE float (32 bits = 4 bytes) and double (64 bits = 8 bytes). So there will normally be a type of the same size. No doubt there are some "weird" architectures out there

But as R.. points out in a comment, that doesn't necessarily mean that all the values of the pointer type can be represented by the floating type, because not all bit patterns are valid values (and some of the ones that are valid are NaNs, and IIRC when you assign a NaN the result is certainly a NaN, but isn't certainly the *same* NaN). So this type does *not* get the effect of `intptr_t`.

Comment: Well, assuming all you are trying to do is cast them back and forth (and not do arithmetic), the "NaN problem" should not matter in practice.

Comment: @Nemo: I've tried to explain why I think it still is a problem, although I may be incorrect about the behaviour of NaNs.

Comment: I suspect in practice that the bit patterns are preserved if all you do is assignment.  But it is obviously not guaranteed...

Comment: The answer seems correct, but if this is what the question was about, I would be interested to learn  what is this casting back and forth assumed to achieve?

Comment: @Suma: I can barely figure out what `intptr_t` is supposed to achieve, let alone a floating-point equivalent ;-)

Comment: @Steve: I think in cases like when writing a memory allocator or analyzer, intptr_t type can make your life easier (e.g. when aligning pointers). Still, even with the lowest level coding I ever did, I cannot imagine how I could use floats as for something useful with pointers.

Comment: @Suma: true, although such things are implementation-specific, so in some sense you could just have used whatever type `intptr_t` is a typedef of. Technically I don't think it's guaranteed that if a pointer is (say) 8-aligned, then converting it to `intptr_t` results in a multiple of 8, or vice-versa. In practice it is true, of course, but there was a portability issue a while ago where I invented an implementation with CHAR_BIT=8 on top of an imaginary architecture that is 4-bit addressable, so that with a natural conversion, `(char*)((intptr_t)p + 2) == ((char*)p + 1)`. Legal, I think.

Comment: ... and it means that all your alignment requirements are twice as big in intptr_t-space as what they are in char*-space. So your "portable" pointer-alignment code falls over.

Comment: While you are technically correct, "portable" can have many flavours. E.g. I often write a code which needs to be portable to all combinations of Windows/Linux vs x86/x64, but nowhere else. For this intptr_t type is excellent aid.

Comment: @Suma: sure, I said I can "barely" figure out the purpose of `intptr_t`, not that I *can't* figure it out. I'm not seriously suggesting that it's useless, just that it's already so niche that I'm stumped for a serious use for a floating-point equivalent. Unless maybe the questioner is doing a *lot* of pointer arithmetic, and hoping to benefit from SIMD. In which case, no chance.

Answer (score 1):

A `float` (a.k.a. single precision) is 4 bytes so... yes, maybe.

Note that not all 4 byte values are valid floats, some are `NaN`, not a number.

The tone of your question makes me think you've heard something about atomic operations on entities the size of the processor bus. If that's true then `DON'T do it`, use explicit atomic operations. They make for more readable code and less bugs.